# sessions usage in codeigniter and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, session

I'm working on a project in which my codeigniter is placed inside the wordpress main folder,following is structure of my project.

```
    //codeigniter_folder
    //wp-admin
    //wp-content
    //wp-includes
    //other wordpress files
```

codeigniter_folder have codeigniter files in it.
As I'm using session in codeigniter and I want to access that session in wordpress.But when I echo session_id() in codeigniter it gives me different value and when I echo session_id() in wordpress it gives me different session id.I'm not understanding why different sessions are being used in one main directory(project directory),how can I use codeigniter's session inside the wordpress(only front end,not for wp-admin).

Comment: Try the cookie system of CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has own session structure,
if you want use other session that made by other script, I think you must use `$_SESSION[]` variable

Comment: I used $_SESSION but it gives different values for both codeigniter and wordpress

Comment: I think they encrypt their sessions for security reason